# spark spawns multiple jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am very confused with spark behavior, I hope someone can help to understand it.
What I understand is spark creates job whenever it encounters an action. But here I have 2 below scenarios:

Scenario 1:
Here, I simply read a file to create dataframe & run `df.show()` to see the contents of file, and spark creates only one job as shown in below image.
[image: Scenario 1 Image]

Scenario 2:
Here, I simply read a file to create dataframe, after that I groupBy based on department to file count department wise and run show to display the output, and here spark creates multiple jobs but we have only one action here, that's what confusing me.
[image: Scenario 2 Image]

Below is the code,
In Scenario 1 groupBy was commented.
In Scenario 2 groupBy ran.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

data_schema = StructType([
    StructField("emp_name", StringType()),
    StructField("department", StringType()),
    StructField("salary", DoubleType())
])

df = spark.read\
        .format("csv")\
        .schema(data_schema)\
        .option("sep", "|")\
        .option("header", True)\
        .option("ignoreLeadingSpaces", True)\
        .option("ignoreTrailingSpaces", True)\
        .load("dbfs:/FileStore/practise/employee_new-1.csv")

# df = df.groupBy('department').count()

df.show()
```

**I just want to know why we have 2 jobs in Scenario 2 when we have only one action & in what all scenarios spark creates multiple jobs with one action.**

Comment: Why do you # on # df = df.groupBy('department').count() ? Unclear what you ran.

Comment: that's what I have explained in above 2 scenarios, first one was with comment & second was with groupBy

Comment: Groupby and count.

Comment: but `groupBy().count()` is a transformation.
It is creating a stage because it requires shuffle, I understand that, but why there is a new job created.

Comment: If you did not comment out df.show() in scenario 2 then it has 2 jobs due to having 2 actions(show and count)

Comment: as far as I know, count with groupBy is not an action

Answer (score 0):

`count` and `show()` are Actions: hence 2 Jobs.

The 2nd Action does not repeat all steps.

See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spark-transformations-actions-lazy-evaluation-mohammad-younus-jameel/

Comment: as far as I know, count with groupBy is not an action